# Отследить уход со страницы

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь переадресовать пользователя на другую страницу таким вот способом

```
window.location.href="test.com";
```

При этом браузер говорит, что есть не сохраненные данные, точно ли я хочу покинуть страницу...
Опытным путем я нашел сл. строки которые, как я понимаю, отвечают за отслеживание покидания страницы.

```
t(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
                            
                          if (globals.leaveMessage){ 
                          return e.TR(globals.leaveMessage)
                          }
                       })
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как видоизменить данный код, что бы браузер перестал предупреждать пользователя о несохраненных данных?

Comment: просто удалить обработчик `beforeunload` целиком.

Answer (score 0):

```
t(window).off("beforeunload");
```

или

```
globals.leaveMessage = false;
```